# Excel VBA: Formulas not working with CopyFromRecordset, only when manually inserted

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

My formulas won't recalculate when i insert CopyFromRecordset, only if I insert it manually from an SQL query.

I have a connection set up to a SQL table, which returns a set of rows and inserts them into my table. In the same sheet, I have a few formulas (SUM.IF types) in a column next to the data. The connection works fine, the inserted data looks fine.
When I copy the data from SQL query and insert into my excel sheet, the formulas can recalculate and works.
When I use my CopyFromRecordset, the formulas will not recalculate and just outputs "-".

Cell formats are not changed. The formulas still look right and the same when I have insert CopyFromRecordset. 
Why won't the formulas update when I try to recalculate??

The code I use:

```
sht.Select
//Selects old records and clears them
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Range("A2:L" & LastRow)
DataRange.Select
DataRange.ClearContents
//Gets data from SQL query and inserts to sheet
strSQL = "selects column 1,2,3 from table"
rs.ActiveConnection = Conn
rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 1, 1
sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

And all I get from my SUM.IF formula is "-".

Comment: If you recalculate (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9) do your formulas refresh?  Or try adding `sht.UsedRange.Calculate` after the code shown.

Comment: I have tried both, but it still doesn't help. I stil get "-"

Comment: Can you show an example of a full formula?  Does a simpler formula (eg. a link to a single cell) also not recalculate?  Have you tried `CalculateFullRebuild ` ?

Comment: The formula is: =SUM.IF(J:J;M3;A:A), where the J column contains texts fields, M3 is a textfield, and A is a number. So it check if the text in column J is equal to M3, and then counts from column A.
If i do a simple reference to a cell or a SUM(A:A) it returns the correct output. 

I just tried adding the CalculateFullRebuild to end of the code, but nothing changed

Comment: Do you mean `SUMIF()` ?  Not sure about `SUM.IF()`

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a Danish excel version, so I just roughly translated it. In the danish version it is "SUM.HVIS()", and it works fine in any other formula. (like I've mentioned, when I manually copy the data into the sheet, the formulars work)

Comment: Do you have a custom format on those cells to show a `-` instead of zero?

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that it looks like the number fields look different when I manually copy them. The cell format is still "number", but it looks like the CopyFromRecordset somehow converts them into not looking like a number. So, manually they look like "1.00" and with CopyFromRecordset they look like "1". If I only manually copy this column, and use CopyFromRecordset with the rest of the columns, the formulars work!

Comment: Seems like there is a known issue with `CopyFromRecordset` changing cell formatting.  You can instead loop over the recordset and write the values (will be a little slower but manageable if you turn off Calculation/Screenupdating...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem was that the column containing numbers was not formatted corretly. The excel column was correctly formatted, but apparently the data coming from SQL was sent in varchar format. So the CopyFromRecordset just pours the data into the sheet, and the numbers didn't get re-formatted, and my SUMIF() wouldn't accept it as numbers. I just changed my sql line to convert that column into float

```
strSQL = "SELECT  CONVERT(float,[numberColumn]) AS [number], column2, column3"
```

Everything works fine now! :D